# Ayuda para completar el siguiente código

Tags: php, formularios, email

Bueno primero les diré lo que quiero hacer. Quiero que los usuarios me contacten a través de un formulario y  me llegue al correo.

Una vez conseguí un código completo en PHP pero lo perdí entonces accedí a un host donde lo había subido pero lo había editado y lo dañé, ahora quisiera que me ayudaran a corregirlo debido a que tiene algunos errores y no tengo conocimientos en PHP.

```
<?php
//Recibimos los campos del formulario
$nombre=$_POST[nombres];
$apellido=$_POST[apellidos];
$correo=$_POST[correo];
$Ayuda=$_POST[ayuda];


$texto_mensaje=
'Nombres:'.$nombres;
'Apellidos:'.$apellidos;
'Menssaje de ayuda:' .$Ayuda;


Puedes contactarlo a su correo: .$correo;
mail("ejemplo@eldominio.com",$asunto,$texto_mensaje);
echo "" ;
?>
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el error que te arroja.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en $texto_mensaje, para concatenar siempre con "."
En el caso de querer seguir concatenando posteriormente se puede hacer con $texto_mesane .= $variable.'texto'

```
<?php
//Recibimos los campos del formulario
$nombre=$_POST[nombres];
$apellido=$_POST[apellidos];
$correo=$_POST[correo];
$Ayuda=$_POST[ayuda];


$texto_mensaje=
'Nombres:'.$nombres
.'Apellidos:'.$apellidos
.'Menssaje de ayuda:' .$Ayuda
.'Puedes contactarlo a su correo:'.$correo;

mail("ejemplo@eldominio.com",$asunto,$texto_mensaje);
echo "" ;
?>
```